# What is the difference between an Enhanced and an Extended Adobe Stock Image License?

Tags: images, stock-images

I'd like to use an image from Adobe Stock on a product label for a client who wants unlimited use of the image in print (on his product). I looked at the licensing info on Adobe's website - and it says that a Standard License only covers up to 500,000 prints. There is also an Enhanced License and an Extended License, but I can't figure out the difference, and which I'd need to purchase!

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: It's all there https://stock.adobe.com/license-terms

Answer (score 1):

Standard license as you understand lets you to cover up 500.000 prints only for illustration purpose.
The Enhanced license removes that restriction and lets you to use it on mugs, t-shirts and other kind of merchandise.
The Extended license has all the rights as the enhanced license, but you can also use it to create product and resell it.